Package R does not exist error: Andriod studio verison 9
I've opened an empty Java project in Android Studio, and when I ran it, there was a Gradle issue. I updated the Gradle, and now I am getting an "r package does not exist" error. How do I deal with this? I've cleaned and rebuilt, there are no errors in the xml file and invalidated cache.
same problem.
here is my gradle version: ```plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}
android {
namespace 'com.example.uiwindowboxes'
compileSdk 34
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.uiwindowboxes"
    minSdk 28
    targetSdk 34
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

}
dependencies {
// implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.7.0' was the original
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.2.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.6.1'

}



I am using version 9 of Android Studio.  




Here is the error message: 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Ypj4lSx7.png


can u share the error logs?

There is no "Android Studio version 9" see history on Wikipedia. Go to help -> About to see your version.

Did you try to do the import manually ex : "com.example.myapp.R" (replace with your package name) where you need it ?
Can you also provide a sceen of the error please ? The error is raised in a .kt or .java file ?
